# Upgrade Error: Ubuntu Server 19.10 to 20.04 - Raspberry

Tags: server, upgrade, 20.04, 19.10, raspberrypi

trying to upgrade from Ubuntu Server 19.10 (on raspberry) to 20.04 - at the end I get the following error:

```
Error during update

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of
network problem, please check your network connection and retry.

E:Failed to fetch
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-arm64/Packages
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80], E:Failed to fetch
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80], E:Failed to fetch
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80], E:Some index files failed to
download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Complete output:

```
ubuntu@malbun:~$ do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife


0% [Working]                                                                   
0% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com]                                          
0% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.152)]                          
0% [Connected to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.152)]                           
0% [Waiting for headers]                                                       
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1,554 B]                                         

99% [1  1,554 B/1,554 B 100%]                                                  
99% [Working]                                                                  
99% [Waiting for headers]                                                      
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,341 kB]                                                  

0% [2  8,443 B/1,341 kB 0%]                                                    
100% [Working]                                                                 
Fetched 1,343 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'focal.tar.gz'
screenrc: log: window required  
Reading cache

Checking package manager
...
...
...
...
...                                                 

Error during update 

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of 
network problem, please check your network connection and retry. 

E:Failed to fetch 
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-arm64/Packages 
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80], E:Failed to fetch 
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages 
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80], E:Failed to fetch 
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages 
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80], E:Some index files failed to 
download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead. 


Restoring original system state



Reading state information... Done
=== Command detached from window (Mon Jan 25 11:30:11 2021) ===
```

Comment: The URL you mention doesn't provide support for arm64 (http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/)  arm64 is found in ports - http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/

Comment: Thank you.... but how would I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem for a week, it seems that when upgrading it fetches information from the "wrong" repository (http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/) and I can't figure how to change this destination to the http://ports.ubuntu.com which is the repository currently having Fossa arm64 Package.
I tried also changing the URL located in `/etc/update-manager/meta-release`, used during the upgrade process to fetch the new mirror, with no success because the content URL redirects to a list of distros each with their correspondent release-URL, for example for Focal Fossa:

````
Dist: focal
Name: Focal Fossa
Version: 20.04.1 LTS
Date: Thu, 23 April 2020 20:04:00 UTC
Supported: 1
Description: This is the 20.04.1 LTS release
Release-File: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/Release
ReleaseNotes: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/ReleaseAnnouncement
ReleaseNotesHtml: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/ReleaseAnnouncement.html
UpgradeTool: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/focal.tar.gz
UpgradeToolSignature: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/focal.tar.gz.gpg```
````